# React Native - Navigate to Dashboard if token is available

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am making an application with a basic Login and Logout feature. Below is my Nested Stack Navigator in React Navigation (V5).

```
// App.js

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function noAuth() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={Loading} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function bottomTapNavigator() {
  var role = this.props.role; // from redux

  if (role === 'admin') {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#E9786F',
          showIcon: true,
          inactiveTintColor: '#000',
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Employees" component={EmployeeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Members" component={MembersScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Statistics" component={StatisticsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  } else if (role === 'employee') {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#E9786F',
          showIcon: true,
          inactiveTintColor: '#000',
          // style: styles.tabBar,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

export default class Screens extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          {(this.props.accessToken == null) | '' ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Root} />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using a condition to check if token is avaialble or not in the async storage through reducer.
If it is available, the DASHBOARD screen(BOTTOM NAVIGATOR) will be the MAIN STACK and if not then the AUTH screen(STACK NAVIGATOR) will be main Stack. I am using this condition to prevent the user to go back to login screen if they press back button.

The Loading screen is the starting screen that checks for the token.

```
//Loading.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as RootNavigation from '../../actions/RootNavigation';
import {StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
class Loading extends Component {
  userAuth = async () => {
    alert('EMTERED');
    const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    const refreshToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');

    this.props.setOnlyToken(accessToken, refreshToken);

    //Redirecting the user as per the token
    this.props.navigation.navigate(accessToken != null ? 'Dashboard' : 'Auth');

    { I have used the below methods also but no success}

    // if (accessToken != null) {
    //   this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push('Dashboard'));
    // } else {
    //   RootNavigation.navigate('Login');
    // }


    // {
    //   accessToken != null
    //     ? RootNavigation.navigate('Dashboard', {});
    //     : RootNavigation.navigate('Login', {});
    // }


  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.userAuth();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
        <ActivityIndicator size={100} color="#812727" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    apiCalls: state.apiCalls,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    setOnlyToken: (aToken, rToken) =>
      dispatch({type: 'setOnlyToken', value1: aToken, value2: rToken}),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Loading);
```

In my screnario the user is logged in and it should through me to the DASHBOARD screen in which the HOME is the initial Route for DASHBOARD stack but it throws this error.

[image: Error message]

I have read the following document
- [Nesting Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)
- [Navigation without Navigation props](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop)

Please if anyone review and tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, in order to be able to navigate through scenes, you need to *register* them.

You would have something like:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const SettingsScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And then in your index.js, you would import it and register, so that you are able to go through the scenes:

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Note: In order to combine with Stack Navigation to push others scenes, check the article on the link section.

**Links:**

- [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation)
- [Article using React Navigation](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/combining-stack-navigator-with-tab-navigator-in-react-native-react-navigation-253656f45181) with Tab navigation + Stack

Comment: I am using React Native Navigation (V5)

Comment: I just checked your code, and you're actually using the "react-navigation" library. The "react-native-navigation" is another one. I will update your tag and my answer.

Comment: @ShahbazShaikh please check my update. Note that it is a simple example that can be structure in a bunch of ways. In the end, you register the entire Container of the App that includes your scenes in each tab.